# Can two custom methods be added to ngx-restangular resource?

Tags: angular, restangular

I'm configuring an ngx-restangular resource with more than one method, but only the first method is being recognized as a function. With the following configuration, the `feature` function is recognized, but not the `nearest` function.

```
restangular.withConfig(
  (configurer) => {

    /* Add Auth header to each request. */
    configurer.addFullRequestInterceptor(
      (element, operation, path, url, headers, params) => {
        return {
          headers: Object.assign({}, headers, {Authorization: `Bearer ${creds.getBearerToken()}`})
        };
      }
    );

    /* For a given locationId, provide a feature set (geometry) for the location. */
    configurer.addElementTransformer('location', false,
      (resource) => {
        resource.addRestangularMethod(
          'feature',
          'get',
          'map'
        );
        return resource;
      }
    );

    /* Resource providing Nearest Location instances suitable for edit. */
    configurer.addElementTransformer('location', true,
      (resource) => {
        resource.addRestangularMethod(
          'nearest',
          'get',
          'nearest'
        );
        return resource;
      }
    );

  }
);
return restangular.service('location');
```

Is it possible to add more than one Restangular Method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. I got this working by invoking `withConfig` for each method to be added:

```
restangular.withConfig(
  (configurer) => {

    /* Add Auth header to each request. */
    configurer.addFullRequestInterceptor(
      (element, operation, path, url, headers, params) => {
        return {
          headers: Object.assign({}, headers, {Authorization: `Bearer ${creds.getBearerToken()}`})
        };
      }
    );

    /* For a given locationId, provide a feature set (geometry) for the location. */
    configurer.addElementTransformer('location', false,
      (resource) => {
        resource.addRestangularMethod(
          'feature',
          'get',
          'map'
        );
        return resource;
      }
    );

  }
);

restangular.withConfig(
  (configurer) => {

    /* Add Auth header to each request. */
    configurer.addFullRequestInterceptor(
      (element, operation, path, url, headers, params) => {
        return {
          headers: Object.assign({}, headers, {Authorization: `Bearer ${creds.getBearerToken()}`})
        };
      }
    );

    /* Resource providing Nearest Location instances suitable for edit. */
    configurer.addElementTransformer('location', true,
      (resource) => {
        resource.addRestangularMethod(
          'nearest',
          'get',
          'nearest'
        );
        return resource;
      }
    );

  }
);
return restangular.service('location');
```

Adding the auth header for each is also necessary when added as part of the `withConfig`.